# how to configure the interval of lsyncd monitoring files changes?

Tags: linux, synchronization, rsync, inotify

as you know, lsyncd can watching local file changes and trigger rsync to sync files chanages to remote server. my question is how to configure the interval of lsyncd monitoring files changes?
I have not found any paramters in lsyncd.conf, any clue will be appreciated.

thanks,
Emre

Answer (score 8):

I think it's not possible to configure the interval that lsyncd monitors file changes as lsyncd rather is event based, so the local directory tree is monitored through the event monitor interface (inotify or fsevents) which means in a sense it is always watching.

What you can influence is the time lsyncd aggregates changes before it spawns a rsync call (by default this is 15 seconds) by providing the `delay` parameter.

```
sync{default.rsync, source="dir", target="dir", delay=25}
```

Setting it to 0 will cause it to sync as early as possible.

Comment: Is there any downside to having a short delay?

Comment: Was wondering about this delay too, it seems the longer the delay the more events can be compacted into a single rsync call. So guess if you don't have too many changes there isn't much of a downside. If you do have many changes it will be more inefficient as it cannot group multiple events into a single call. Source: https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd/issues/387